# Reordering files using NSFileManager on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsfilemanager

I have a question on the NSFileManager.

I store a collection of images in the Documents directory in an iPhone app.

basically they are stored as img0001.jpg, img0002.jpg,...img0010.jpg.

I am using a table view to show a list of these images ( I loop through the directory and put them in an NSArray to show in the table.), but I would like to allow the user to re-order these. I wanted to rename the image based of where they moved it in the UITableView.

So if they move img0008.jpg to row 5, it would become img0005.jpg, and everything underneath it will be renamed to 6,7,8 etc...

I was curious if anyone else had a need to do this?  If so, how did you attack it? I think it is something that is very possible, I am just hitting a wall at the moment.

If I solve this before someone replies, I will make sure that I post my solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create an array of the files and order them in the array, then display the re-ordered array of the directory contents.

Comment: And if you want the ordering to be permanent, then save that array of filenames in a separate file. Renaming all the files could be very time consuming and potentially error-prone (what happens if your app is terminated due to low memory halfway through renaming all the files?)

Comment: I have to be honest, I never thought of the low memory potential.  I think it makes more sense to just store my images, and manage the order in an NSArray, that will allow a little more flexibility and should be faster as well.  I just need to remember to modify the array when I add/delete images to the documents directory.  I will try this later today and post my results.

Comment: Just a follow-up.  I was able to do this.  It seems to working pretty well (and quick) .  I just have to change my add/delete functions when it comes to adding and deleting images so I update the NSArray.

Thanks again for your help!